# Wrapp every form item select with div, excluding label

Tags: forms

im trying  to wrap form item  with

I had success with hook_from_alter and #prefix #suffix that is wrapping whole element with div like this:

I used this hook:

```
function em_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['field_gender'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#prefix'] = '<div class="custom-select">';
    $form['field_gender'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#sufix'] = '</div">';
}
}
```

And i got this.

```
<div class="custom-select">
<div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-field-gender-und">
    <label for="edit-field-gender-und">Gender</label>
    <select id="edit-field-gender-und" name="field_gender[und]" class="form-select required">
        <option value="_none">- Select a value -</option>
        <option value="1">Male</option>
        <option value="2">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

But what i need to accomplish is this:

```
<div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-field-gender-und">
<label for="edit-field-gender-und">Gender</label>
<div class="custom-select">
    <select id="edit-field-gender-und" name="field_gender[und]" class="form-select required">
        <option value="_none">- Select a value -</option>
        <option value="1">Male</option>
        <option value="2">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And i would like to have this on every select on whole website, so maybe hook_form_alter isn`t so good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This theme function should do what you need.

```
function mytheme_select($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'size'));
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-select'));

  return '<div class="custom-select"><select' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . form_select_options($element) . '</select></div>';
}
```